# Vectorize for-loop which combines two different dataframes

Tags: python, for-loop, vectorization

I have a two-columns dataframe that contains the input data.
The first column is a starting date and the second is called duration (minutes). You can think of a machine that runs from start to start+duration.
I want to use this information to build an 1d-array of length 8760*60 that contains all the minutes of the year and there should be a 1 at the place where the machine runs and a zero otherwise.
The following MWE does the task, but is slow because of the for-loop and I would not know how to vectorize it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Start and end of time horizon
start = pd.Timestamp(year=2019, month=1, day=1, hour=0, tz='UTC')
end = pd.Timestamp(year=2019, month=12, day=31, hour=23, minute=59, tz='UTC')

# DataFrame of time horizon
dates = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start, end, freq='min'))

# Starting points
t1 = pd.Timestamp(year=2019, month=1, day=2, hour=0, tz='UTC')
t2 = pd.Timestamp(year=2019, month=1, day=1, hour=0, minute=3, tz='UTC')

# Durations
d1 = 5
d2 = 30

# DataFrame from input data
data = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        [t1, d1],
        [t2, d2],
        ],
    columns=[
        'start',
        'duration',
        ]
    )

# Array to be filled
on = np.zeros(8760*60)

# loop over data rows 
for idx in data.index:
    # Start for on array from dates 
    start = dates[dates[0] == data.loc[idx, 'start']].index[0]
    
    # Duration from data
    duration = data.loc[idx, 'duration']

    # Put 1s in the on array from start to start+duration
    on[start: start+duration] = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you:

```
idx = pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp('2019-01-01', tz='UTC'),
                    pd.Timestamp('2019-12-31', tz='UTC'),
                    freq='1min')
df = pd.DataFrame({'on': 0}, index=idx)

def to_mins(row):
    return set(pd.date_range(row['start'], periods=row['duration'], freq='1min'))

idx_on = set().union(*data[['start', 'duration']].apply(to_mins, axis='columns'))
df.loc[idx_on] = 1
on = df.on.values
```

If it's possible that the duration leads to timestamps outside of 2019, you could use:

```
def to_min_range(row):
    return set(
        m 
        for m in pd.date_range(row['start'], periods=row['duration'], freq='1min')
        if m.year == 2019
    )
```

Comment: Interesting solution! However, since you are using apply, I'm not sure it's much faster than OP's for-loop.

Comment: I added an alternative, still using `apply`, but most likely fewer times, depends on the rows in `data`

Answer (score 1):

```
idx = pd.date_range(start, end, freq="min").to_series()
data["duration"] = pd.to_timedelta(data.duration, unit="min")
res = pd.concat(
    [
        i.to_series()
        for i in data.apply(
            lambda row: pd.date_range(row[0], row.sum(), freq="min", closed="right"),
            axis=1,
        )
    ]
)
_, res = idx.align(res)
on = (~res.isna()).astype("int").values
```

This also uses `apply` `len(data)` times, hopefully that's a much smaller number than the number of minutes in a year.

**EDIT:**

The time intervals are closed on both ends.  In the comments the OP mentioned they expect the sum to match the total duration the equipment was on, this can be achieved by making one of the ends of the interval open.  Since the sum is expected to be the duration it's on, I chose `right`.

Comment: I got a total duration of sum(on)=37 mins for my example. But it should be 35, doesn't it?

Comment: The number of times `apply` is used in my proposal is `len(data)` too - or did I miss something?

Comment: @clueless You are getting 1 for each time period, every starting timestamp is also counted: start, start + 1, start + 2, gets counted as 3.  I guess you could adjust for that in the list of timestamps, but probably the easier option is to do `on.sum() - len(data)`.

Comment: @Timus you are right, I misread your algorithm :-p I was attempting another approach using `reshape`, but couldn't find a way to fill in the intermediate minutes without iteration.  Maybe `apply` is unavoidable :-/

Comment: @clueless I edited my response to address the both sided interval issue, no need to correct with `len(data)` now.